# Why am I getting a Port error after running this?

Tags: java, swing, japplet, jeditorpane

I created this in textpad because our instructor doesn't want us using IDE's. I am trying to type a website in and view it in the `JEditorPane`.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ViewRemoteFile extends JApplet
    {
        private JButton jbtView = new JButton("View");
        private JTextField jtfURL = new JTextField(12);
        private JEditorPane jtaFile = new JEditorPane();
        private JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel();

        public void init()
        {
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            p1.add(new JLabel("URL"), BorderLayout.WEST);
            p1.add(jtfURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p1.add(jbtView, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(new JScrollPane(jtaFile), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            jbtView.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    showFile();
                }
            });
        }

        private void showFile()
        {
            //Scanner input = null;
            //URL url = null;

            try
            {
                jtaFile.setPage(new URL(jtfURL.getText().trim()));
                jlblStatus.setText("File loaded successfully");
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                jlblStatus.setText("URL " + jtfURL.getText().trim() + " not found.");
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                jlblStatus.setText(ex.getMessage());
            }
            /*finally
            {
                if(input != null)
                    input.close();
            }*/
        }
    }
```

When I run this code it doesn't show the site and it crashes and fills my console with a ton of errors.

for http://www.yahoo.com  I get :

```
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.Socket
Permission" "www.yahoo.com:80" "connect,resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:366)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
555)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:466)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:992)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:928)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:846)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1296)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468
)
        ... 40 more
```

Comment: What the errors you are getting?

Comment: For http://www.yahoo.com I get the following errors in the console window:

Comment: added to the bottom of my code

Comment: Any idea on what the error is for??

Comment: It appears that your `SecurityManager` is rejecting access to connect to yahoo.com. I've never come across something like this before, I don't really have a clue.

Comment: Okay Thanks ill give it a while longer and work on something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an applet, it needs to be signed to access a socket. An unsigned applet is only allowed to connect to the host it came from. Check out [Signed Applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) and [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

**EDIT**: display HTML documents:

I'm not sure what is your objective, but if you want to display HTML page you may find `showDocument` useful. Here is an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/browser.html).

Comment: Thanks I am looking into this now.

Comment: @user512915 maybe `showDocument` can help you, see my edit.